# How to add tracking number to Magento Rest API

Tags: rest, api, magento

Is there a way to add a tracking number to Orders in Magento Rest API?
This the documentation I am referring to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/order_items.html#RESTAPI-Resource-OrderItems-HTTPMethod-GET

and I can't seem to see endpoint to add a tracking number to the Orders.

However, when I checked this docs for SOAP API http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/salesOrderShipment.html
there's an endpoint for adding for Order Shipment.

How can I add the tracking number to orders in REST API for Magento ? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api2.xml` - it lists all the attributes that are returned from an order. You'll need to create a new module and add an extra attribute to the same config path

Comment: Where can I find this ?

Comment: Find what? I just gave you the file path